# Can the unbounded knapsack problem (UKP) be solved efficiently when the weights equal the values?

Tags: integer-programming, np-complete

As defined at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem), UKP is defined as follows:

Let $v_i$ be the given values of the objects, $w_i$ their given weights, $W$ the given maximum weight capacity of the knapsack, and $x_i$ the decision variables that are non-negative integers.

$\max{\sum v_i x_i}$,

subject to $\sum w_i x_i \leq W$ and $x_i \geq 0$.

I want to know if this problem can be solved efficiently when the values are equal to the weights and they are real values. So we would get:

$\max{\sum w_i x_i}$,

subject to $\sum w_i x_i \leq W$ and $x_i \geq 0$.

The decision version of UKP is NP-complete for the general case, but since this is a specific case, I was wondering if it can be solved efficiently. **Note** that the weights can be real values, so dynamic programming, like shown on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) would not really work.

Comment: Are these truly **real** inputs, or just rational inputs in a common base (decimal/binary)?  How are you representing real values?  What is your complexity model for operations on real values?

Comment: I guess the problem I want to solve only takes fractions as input. To be more precise floating points. So multiplying them with the lowest common denominator to get integers would be a bit troublesome, since the integers you get could become too large for dynamic programming.

Comment: If you don’t get an answer here, you might consider asking on the new [or.se] Stack.